# JS how to make a window call the script that created it?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a window and then for that window to call the script that created an so on. Here:[image]

There is time and number of windows. So it a quadratic acent in the number of windows because when the first window creates another after one second both windows will create another one etc.

Here is my current code but i do not know **how to get the created window to call the script that created it**.

```
var URL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"


function openWindow() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth))
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerHeight))
    var width = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth)
    var height = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight)
    window.open(URL, "_blank", "width="+width+",height="+height+",left="+x+",top="+y)
}

setInterval(openWindow, 1000)
```

I can get the window to open but I am new to JS so do not know how to make it run the script that created it.

Well I have tried looking on google and asking around

Answer (score 1):

Short as it may be, I don't think I can ellaborate any more than this:  You access the window that opened a window using `window.opener`.  Here's the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener).